# Array of dates from current date

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

Good day.

Ive been trying to get the days from the current day using Carbon in Laravel. So if today is the December 20 I want to get an array with:

```
December 20, 2018
December 21, 2018
December 22, 2018
December 23, 2018
December 24, 2018
```

I want to do it for 2 weeks or maybe even 3 weeks. This is what I got so far.

```
$currentdate = Carbon::now()->format('m/d/Y');
$ts = strtotime($currentdate);

$year = date('o', $ts);
$week = date('W', $ts);

$datearray = [];
for($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
   $ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
   array_push($datearray,date("m/d/Y", $ts));
}
```

The code above gives me for the week from the starting of the week and not from the day going forward.

Comment: Look into this answer [PHP Carbon, get all dates between date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50854594/3226121)

Comment: Carbon has some great methods for getting and settings dates, such as addDay() and toDateString. It might be easier than what you're trying to do here. Check out their [docs here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: in carbon use `addDays(1);` in a loop, your mixing in legacy strtotime for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using `Carbon`, use its power!

```php
use \Carbon\Carbon;

// how many days you want in your array
$count = 7;
$dates = [];
$date = Carbon::now();
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $dates[] = $date->addDay()->format('F d, Y');
}

// Show me what you got
print_r($dates);
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => December 22, 2018
    [1] => December 23, 2018
    [2] => December 24, 2018
    [3] => December 25, 2018
    [4] => December 26, 2018
    [5] => December 27, 2018
    [6] => December 28, 2018
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$datearray = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
   array_push($datearray, date('F d, Y', strtotime($i == 0 ?'today UTC':'today +'.$i.'day')));
   //push to array as 'December 20, 2018'
}
```

enjoy coding~! :)

Comment: why use carbon ignore all its  methods and revert to strtotime?

Comment: @tim, It has a lot of useful built-in functions and is easy to develop than original function of PHP Data.:) https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/"

Comment: exactly, so why not use them?

Comment: @tim, you can use that in your code if you want more performance, built-in function also included  PHP methods in internal :)

Comment: if that's why you think why are you using `Carbon::now` ? you cant have it both ways.

Comment: @tim, please check this, I learned PHP `Date` is better than `Carbon` because of you. thanks:p https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113905/which-is-faster-php-date-functions-or-carbon